# Как скрыть блок не только для одной страницы, а для всей категории

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как скрыть блок не только на одной странице, но и на страницах, входящих в эту категорию. Для отзывов я решила проблему с помощью такого кода:

```
<?php if (in_array('otzivi', explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) { ?>
    <style>
        #news {display:none;}
        #otzivi {display:none;}
        #podelitsya {display:none;}
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

Там урлы идут через слеш /: ...index.php/otzivi/2. Теперь мне нужно убрать эти же блоки в новостях, но код не работает из-за того, что теперь урлы выглядят так: ... index.php/novosti?start=4 . И объясните, пожалуйста, что делает функция explode.

Comment: Может, имеет смысл не тащить на клиент ненужный HTML, включая дополнительный `<style></style>`, а просто отредактировать шаблон таким образом, чтобы блок не показывался "физически", а не "висел с display:none;", как у Вас и автора ответа?

Comment: Пробовала, не получается. Движок на джумле, поэтому осуществить это затруднительно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Функция explode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) - описание по ссылке, в вашем случае функция разбивает url по разделителю "/" и делает из получившихся данных массив, а с помощью [функции in_array()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php) проверяет есть ли в получившемся массиве искомое значение.

Например, url вида "index.php/otzivi/2" с помощью `explode()` разбирается на массив `array("index.php", "otzivi", "2")`, ну а дальше с помощью `in_array()` проверяет есть ли в этом массиве "otzivi" и если есть, то стили применяются.

Условие будет выглядеть так (разделил по строчкам, чтобы выглядело понятно):

```
<?php if (
    in_array('otzivi', explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) ||
    in_array('novosti', explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
  ) { ?>
    <style>
       #news {display:none;}
       #otzivi {display:none;}
       #podelitsya {display:none;}
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь ясно!